# mysql update query takes too long

Tags: mysql

i have a table with 2255440 records,

a cron job works every minute and inserts upto 50-100 records on every execution

inserts are working fine

the problem is that there is another cron job which is also running every minute.. this cron job updates these records according to the data recieved from other server

the problem is that the update query is taking around 6 - 7 seconds per update query

this is the table information and update query example

[image]

[image]

[image]

records are updated with this query

**Query:**

```
UPDATE `$month`
SET `acctstoptime`='$data->acctstoptime',
    `acctsessiontime`='$data->acctsessiontime',
    `acctinputoctets`='$data->acctinputoctets',
    `acctoutputoctets`='$data->acctoutputoctets',
    `acctterminatecause`='$data->acctterminatecause'
WHERE `radacctid`=$data->radacctid
```

Comment: I can suggest that an index on `radacctid` _might_ improve the update.  You may try adding that index and then running `EXPLAIN` on the update query.

Comment: Is `radacctid` unique per month? Is the `id` column used? If both, maybe `radacctid` should be the primary key.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Is there a single-column index on column of 'radacctid'?

If not you should create one.

Comment: yes i made 'radacctid' as indexed coloumn and now update query is working fast

Answer (score 0):

**CREATE INDEX:**

> Indexes are used to retrieve data from the database more quickly than
>   otherwise. The users cannot see the indexes, they are just used to
>   speed up searches/queries.

**Syntax**:

```
CREATE INDEX [index name] ON [table name]([column name]);
```

**Arguments**

```
Name            Description

index name      Name of the index.
table name      Name of the table.
column name     Name of the column.
```

> Example

Code:

```
CREATE  INDEX radacctid ON table_name(radacctid);
```